# ChartJS/ ChartJS-plugin annotation set height of vertical line

Tags: chart.js, linechart

Is it possible to set the height of a vertical line in chart js ?
[image]

For instance this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/caj89x6L/

```
{
  type: 'line',
  id: 'vline' + index,
  mode: 'vertical',
  scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
  value: date,
  **endValue: 3.5, ?? 
  height: 3.5,** ?? 
  borderColor: 'green',
  borderWidth: 1,
  label: {
     enabled: true,
     position: "center",
     content: amount[index]
  }
```

}

Can i set somewhere a height property ?
endValue dows not work

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't know if this still helps you, but I wrote a [plugin for ChartJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-lineheight-annotation) which does exactly what you're asking. You may be able to adapt the source code in the [repo](https://github.com/spkellydev/chartjs-plugin-lineheight-annotation#readme) for your own needs. Here's a relevant snippet:

```
  /**
   * Draw the line height annotation to the highest data point on the chart.
   * @param {int} x horizontal coordinate on canvas
   * @param {int} bottomY bottom Y dimension of the chart
   * @param {float} highestDataY highest possible Y value on the chart, taking padding and border offsets into consideration.
   */
  drawLineHeightAnnotation(x, bottomY, highestDataY) {
    let ctx = this.ctx;
    let options = this.options;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    if (!options.noDash) {
      ctx.setLineDash([10, 10]);
    }
    ctx.moveTo(x, highestDataY);
    ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
    ctx.lineWidth = options.lineWeight ? options.lineWeight : 1.5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = options.color ? options.color : "#000";
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
```